# Can I run my Tomcat app on Bluemix?

Tags: tomcat, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

We have a simple app that runs on tomcat7 and has been working for about a year.  We're planning to kick the tires on Bluemix and we would like to know if there's any information that can assist us in this effort. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709061/how-do-i-move-my-existing-websphere-application-to-liberty-on-bluemix/29709062#29709062) that discussed migrating apps from WebSphere Application Server v7 to the Liberty profile but I didn't see any reference to Tomcat. Any documentation or samples you could provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can run your application on Bluemix, however, due to config information spread out in a few different xml files (server, content & web come to mind) on Tomcat,  I suggest you take a staggered approach to moving your app.
You first need to get your app working on the WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Liberty Profile, then you can push a server package to Bluemix.

Essentially, you want to do the following:

1) Migrate your Tomcat application and server config to the Liberty profile using the ***WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit - Competitive Migration***. The article below provides details on the usage of this tool:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/compmig.html

2) Test your app on the Liberty Profile

3) Push the Liberty Server package to bluemix.  I've found the article below useful for pushing server packages:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/01/06/modify-liberty-server-xml-configurations-ibm-bluemix/#

Comment: So after I get things working on Liberty using the approach suggested by @randalanders, then I should use the "cf push" command suggested by @ram-vennam?

Comment: The command I suggested is to use Tomcat. If you want to use Liberty, simply do cf push <appname>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, as I actually want to deploy my app in both environments and monitor the results.

Comment: As an addition to this answer, there several ways to push your packaged Liberty server to Bluemix, you can use the CF CLI ("cf push" command), you can also use DevOps Services or if you use Eclipse (or an Eclipse-based product) you can use the Eclipse Tools for Bluemix

Answer (score 11):

Yup. You can use the community Java buildpack to use Tomcat as your Java runtime.

<s>cf push  -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git</s>

Edit:

```
cf push <appname> -b java_buildpack
```

Doc for Tomcat buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack

The pre-installed buildpack name or external url after `-b` option is the open source java Tomcat buildpack. When pushing a Java application, if you don't specify a buildpack name or url, the default Java buildpack will be chosen. In Bluemix, the default buildpack is the WebSphere Liberty buildpack.

Doc for Liberty buildpack: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications

Comment: Be sure to take Jack-Junjie Cai's answer below into consideration when deciding whether to the the git master url or a named buildpack identifier.  This answer and Jack's should be merged since they are complementary.

Comment: @Ram, I created an app using tomcat 7 in eclipse. It's running locally but when created a war out of that and deployed using your commands to bluemix, I got the error `description The requested resource is not available.`. Can you tell me why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the below command:

```html
cf push <appname> -b java_buildpack
```

This will use the built-in Java buildpack in Bluemix. The benefit of this approach is that you always get the version of the java buildpack that matches the current CloudFoundry level in Bluemix. If you use the external git master, it may or may not work.

Answer (score 3):

As others have explained, Bluemix includes the `java_buildpack` buildpack, which includes Tomcat. To use it to create a runtime in Bluemix using this buildpack, run this command:

```
cf push <appname> -b java_buildpack -p <apparchive>
```

You might wonder: What is this buildpack and what is it doing?

You can see the list of buildpacks avaiable in Bluemix. Run this command:

```
cf buildpacks
```

The output (as of today) is:

```
Getting buildpacks...

buildpack                              position   enabled   locked   filename
liberty-for-java                       1          true      false    buildpack_liberty-for-java_v1.18-20150519-1642-yp.zip
sdk-for-nodejs                         2          true      false    buildpack_sdk-for-nodejs_v1.18-20150519-1759-yp.zip
noop-buildpack                         3          true      false    noop-buildpack-20140311-1519.zip
java_buildpack                         4          true      false    java-buildpack-v2.7.1.zip
ruby_buildpack                         5          true      false    ruby_buildpack-cached-v1.3.0.zip
nodejs_buildpack                       6          true      false    nodejs_buildpack-cached-v1.2.0.zip
go_buildpack                           7          true      false    go_buildpack-cached-v1.2.0.zip
python_buildpack                       8          true      false    python_buildpack-cached-v1.2.0.zip
php_buildpack                          9          true      false    php_buildpack-offline-v3.1.0.zip
aspnet5-experimental                   10         true      false    buildpack_aspnet5-experimental_v0.1.5-20150508-1205.zip
liberty-for-java_v1-17-20150501-1729   11         true      false    buildpack_liberty-for-java_v1.17-20150501-1729-yp.zip
sdk-for-nodejs_v1-17-1-20150519-0951   12         true      false    buildpack_sdk-for-nodejs_v1.17.1-20150519-0951-yp.zip
```

As you can see, the `java_buildpack` buildpack is implemented by `java-buildpack-v2.7.1.zip`. That is documented in [Java Buildpack v2.7.1](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/tag/v2.7.1). As the docs show, the buildpack includes Tomcat v8.0.20.

You can also see that the `liberty-for-java` buildpack, which creates the [Liberty for Java](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html) runtime in Bluemix, is implemented by `buildpack_liberty-for-java_v1.18-20150519-1642-yp.zip`, which is v1.18 of the buildpack. If you need the previous release, you can use the `liberty-for-java_v1-17-20150501-1729` buildpack, which is v1.17 of the buildpack. [Options for pushing Liberty applications](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html) explains how to use the buildpack.

You can also see the buildpacks for Node.js (`nodejs_buildpack`), PHP (`php_buildpack`), and so on. There's even a buildpack for ASP.NET 5 (`aspnet5-experimental`).