# Apache camel support on Bluemix

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Are there any restrictions on usage of Apache Camel Framework in Bluemix ? 
The code will be using a mix of both Spring Framework and Apache Camel API ?

Answer (score 5):

I think it shouldn't be a problem running such kind of app on a Liberty runtime: if you just want to try locally before, you can try to make it run on a local instance of WAS Liberty runtime in its community edition, downloadable from here

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/

If your app could run here, you could be pretty sure to have it running on a Liberty runtime on Bluemix.

Some problems could arise if you need to use Oracle java JDK: in such a case you could anyway make your app run on a Docker container in Bluemix. 
Using a Docker container allows you to solve all the environment limitations existing on Liberty runtime.

You can find a initial documentation about Docker Containers on Bluemix here:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html

Answer (score 2):

The approach identified above is spot on in regards to getting your app running locally before deploying it against Liberty or any other runtime.  I've provided two links below that have some additional details related to migrating (whether from Tomcat or from WAS) to Bluemix.

[Can I run my Tomcat app on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807988/can-i-run-my-tomcat-app-on-bluemix/29808134#29808134)

[How do I move my existing WebSphere application to Liberty on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709061/how-do-i-move-my-existing-websphere-application-to-liberty-on-bluemix/29709062#29709062)

Answer (score 0):

To switch to a tomcat buildpack use a manifest.yml file as follows which specifies the tomcat buildpack rather then liberty or use -b with cf push command to specify the java buildpack which uses tomcat

applications:
- name: myapp
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  host: myappt
  domain: mybluemix.net
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  path: ./target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  services:
    - mysql-db