# What are the best practices to migrate to Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, legacy, paas, hybrid-cloud, public-cloud

I am looking for some documents/guides on how to migrate from other PaaS systems/legacy on premise to Bluemix  - best practices, requirements, etc.
Anything at all would help, thanks, Jason.

Comment: That's a broad question, could you please be more specific on what type of application you want to move to Bluemix? Is it a Java, PHP, Node.js, etc? Does it use any services or database?

Comment: The only best practice I could suggest having no details at all about the applications to migrate is to have an application cloud ready, so without a session management and usage strictly linked to a specific host (sticky sessions for example), and fully scalable on logic and services. Please provide more details to have specific suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite generic, however here are some links regarding the migration from the main technologies:

- From JEE: http://www.slideshare.net/davidcurrie/aai-2698migratingtobluemix
- From LAMP: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-migrate-lamp-app-to-bluemix-trs/index.html
- From other PaaS: http://www.slideshare.net/kelapure/2259-migrate-herokuopenshift-applicationstobluemixpublic

Finally, please note that moving from an on-premise solution to a Cloud Foundry-based one requires some considerations regarding the local file system:

- **Local file system storage is short-lived**. When an application instance crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will start with a new disk image. Although your application can write local files while it is running, the files will disappear after the application restarts.
- **Instances of the same application do not share a local file system**. Each application instance runs in its own isolated container. Thus if your application needs the data in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs to be shared across all running instances of the application, **the local file system should not be used**.
  For this reason local file system should not be used.

If you want more information on this topic please take a look at [Considerations for Designing and Running an Application in the Cloud](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a java app, see the post below:

[Can I run my Tomcat app on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807988/can-i-run-my-tomcat-app-on-bluemix/29808134#29808134)

If you're moving an existing Websphere app, then this will help:

[How do I move my existing WebSphere application to Liberty on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709061/how-do-i-move-my-existing-websphere-application-to-liberty-on-bluemix)

Answer (score 1):

Jason - start here:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/

Then you can watch the YouTube videos:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwYdW8mfXZwJQvB65789_vQ

After that, take a peak at developerWorks:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/devops/plan.html

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate an app from Heroku to Bluemix:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-heroku-migrate-app/